# How to select the first child without knowing its element?

Tags: jquery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $("#container div:first-child").text("foobar");        
    });    
</script>
<div id="container">
    <div>foo</div>
    <div>bar</div>
</div>
```

Will print

```
foobar
bar
```

What's the proper syntax for the selector to select only the first child node regardless of the element it is?

For example how can I change the selector so that

```
<span>foo</span>
<div>bar</div>
```

Would print

```
foobar
bar
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the `div` part of the selector...

```
$("#container :first-child").text("foobar");
```

or you could substitute `*`, but there's no difference...

```
$("#container *:first-child").text("foobar");
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  Interesting how `$("#container :first-child").text("foobar");` works but removing the space before the colon `$("#container:first-child").text("foobar");` doesn't work

Comment: @LedZeppelin: That's because a space is the *[descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector)*. For example, if you do `$('div .some_class')`, you're asking for `.some_class` elements that descend from `div` elements. But if you remove the space, `$('div.some_class')`, now you're asking for `div` elements that themselves have that class. So `$("#container:first-child")` means select `#container`, but *only* if it is the first child of its parent.